# App Script in Sheets. Splitting cells to new sheet and creating new rows if certain values repeat

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking for answers to my problem for a few days on here and wasn't able to find a code solution that works.

I am a newbie and working on the processing of emails. Currently, I managed to brute force the extraction of emails into Rows, whilst deleting most unnecessary text. Now here's my problem.

Here is the link [to the Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19TgAl8K0QXpq_hQoKg6sXBO6HU0nM7SwKXbBV2Py_9E/edit?usp=sharing).

What The current extracted values look like this:

EDIT: I added a Sheet to the above linked sheet titled: "Desired result Example" which showcases the desired result better.

[Extracted values pre split, sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOvf3.png)

[Closeup Row pre split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W5gO.png)
As can be seen here, The email contains info about two shifts. My goal is to transfer the information about the second shift (or third or fourth, each email differs) into a new row. Here's a screenshot of the desired result:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdJPR.png)

Here's the current code I'm using. myFunction and myFunction2 are some of the attempts at sorting it. One of them actually correctly splits the first cell of the last row of data. (it worked on the first cell of all of them before but stopped?(I broke it I guess...)

One other thing I am wondering about is if It'd be possible to create a dynamic regex which would split the dates ( Wed 23 Dec -Fri 25 Dec 2020  / 24-27 Dec 2020 etc.) into two proper date values.. The only idea I currently have is to extract the year and month first and then split "-" and then new Date(day,month,year)? Alternatively us a slice(-4)?

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

```js
function onOpen() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let menuItems = [
    {name: 'Gather emails', functionName: 'gather'},
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Email Extract', menuItems);
}
 function gather() {
    let messages = getGmail();

    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
}
 function getGmail() {
    const query = "from:Test@test.com AND NOT label:done";

    let threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
    if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("done")}

    let messages = [];

    threads.forEach(thread => {
        messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
        label.addToThread(thread);
    });

    return messages;
}
function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/(.*TEST Base Hospital)/g,'TEST Base Hospital*')
        
        //Welcome line
        .replace(/(Hi Agencies)/ig,'')
        .replace(/(Locum)/g,'')
        .replace(/(tourist)/g,'')
        .replace(/(would like to)/ig,'*')
        .replace(/(recall the message)/ig,'RECALL,')
        .replace(/(non-specialist placement)/g,'')
        .replace(/(urgently)/ig,'')
        .replace(/(require)/ig,'')
        .replace(/(needs a|need a| need)/ig,'')
    
        //Specialties
        .replace(/(Obs & Gyn)/ig,'OBGYN*')
        .replace(/((.D\w+.\s\w+\sI\w+\s\w+))/g,'ICU*')
        .replace(/((.D\w+.\s\w+\sM\w+\s\w+))/g,'PSYCH*')
        .replace(/((.D\w+.\s\w+\sE\w+\s\w+|.D\w+.\s\w+\sE\w+))/g,'ED*')
        .replace(/((.D\w+.\s\w+\sMed\w+|Gen Med|Gen\w+\sMed\w+))/ig,'GEN MED*')
        .replace(/((Rad Onc))/ig,'RAD ONC*')
        .replace(/(Psychiatrist)/ig,'PSYCH*')
       
    //Job Positions
        .replace(/(Wards)/ig,'WARDS*')
        .replace(/(Registrar)/g,'REG*')
        .replace(/((.a.+Specialist))/g,'CONSULTANT*') 
        .replace(/( a.Senior Medical Officer)/g,'SMO*')
        .replace(/(.a.FACEM)/g,'FACEM*')
     
    //Experience
        .replace(/((PGY 3+))/ig,'PGY3+*')
        .replace(/(PGY 4+)/ig,'PGY4+*')
        .replace(/(PGY 5+)/ig,'PGY5+*')
    
    //Proper key words
        .replace(/(accommodation|accomm)/ig,'*ACCOMMODATION')
        .replace(/(travel)/ig,'TRAVEL*')

    //Signature
        .replace(/(Best Regards(.|\n|\r)*)/ig,'')
    
        .split('\n');
  

     let result = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20].map(index => parsed[index]);
   
   console.log(result)
  
    return result;
}
   
function myFunction() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lr = ss1.getLastRow();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  for (var i = 0; i <= lr; i++) {
    var title = ss1.getRange(i,1).getValue().split("*");
    ss2.getRange(i, 2).setValue(title[0]);
  }
}
function myFunction2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Selects the spreadsheet
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3"); // Selects sheet 1
  var data = ss1.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets all values in the sheet
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4"); // Selects sheet 2

  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  
      var words = data[i][0].split("*"); // Create an array of all words
  //  if (words[0].toLowerCase().indexOf('hello') > -1) { // True when the first word of the sentence contains hello
    //  words.splice(0, 1); // Remove 1 item, starting from position 0 - remove the word that contains hello
    }
    // Get range on Sheet2, same row number as sheet 1, starting from column 1, select 1 row, and the same amount of columns as the amount of words
    // Because we set values for a range that can span multiple rows, we put the words array in another array (where the words array represents one row)
    // We add 1 to variable i as the index of an array starts at 0 instead of 1.
   console.log(words);
   ss2.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, words.length).setValues([words])
   
  }
```

Comment: About the rows 4 and 5 in your sample image of `Extracted values pre split, sheet`, in this case, can I ask you about the output do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for helping! I added a Tab called " Desired result Example" in the sheet to better see everything. I also allowed for Edits in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I could confirm "Desired result Example" sheet in your shared Spreadsheet. But I cannot understand about your input sheet. Because if "Sheet3" is your input sheet, it seems that the values corresponding to each column are different for each row. So I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal. So I have  asked about `the rows 4 and 5 in your sample image of Extracted values pre split, sheet`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for your quick reply! The Sheet name/number does not matter, as long as it's in a new sheet. I simply added new sheets to test a few different scripts all at once and compare the results side by side on a split screen.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw [Extracted values pre split, sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOvf3.png), I thought that the rows 1 to 3 are different from the rows 4 to 8. In this case, I cannot understand about your expected values and the logic for knowing the corresponding columns for each row. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike The Sheet "Desired result example" [link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19TgAl8K0QXpq_hQoKg6sXBO6HU0nM7SwKXbBV2Py_9E/edit#gid=678493978) Should clearly showcase the problem :)

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. I saw your updated shared Spreadsheet. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for achieving your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. So can you give me a time to do it? When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for my poor understanding.

Comment: Each row seems to have the data formatted in a different way, in different columns. Since the input format and pattern is not clear, I'm not sure a solution can be found here. Please consider clarifying what format would the input data have (what would be in each column, for starters?)

Comment: @lamblichus - The rows in sheet one are the current result when extracting using the code above (function parse email). The data comes from emails and each one does differ. As you see in the code, I am using regex to try and get the keywords as uniform as possible, but my skills are quite limited hence why I’m trying to go step by step and further process the results when transferring to the next sheet. What I think would solve this problem is sorting to an array based on regex value..? I’m really struggling to find a good example.